# C++ Use member function to return value of a struct's pointer property

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, struct, sdl

I'm learning some C++ with SDL and I've run into a confusing issue.

I have a class in a header file:

```
SDL_Surface* loadImage(const char*);

class GameSystem
{
public:
    // Constructor
    GameSystem();
    // Destructor
    ~GameSystem();

    SDL_PixelFormat* screenFormat();
private:
    SDL_Window* m_window;
    SDL_Surface* m_screen;
}

// Global pointer for all to access
extern const GameSystem* g_gameSystem;
```

In the constructor, m_window and m_screen are initialised fine. In the respective source file, I define this member function:

```
SDL_PixelFormat* GameSystem::screenFormat()
{

    return m_screen->format;
}
```

The structure of m_screen is like this:

```
typedef struct SDL_Surface
{
    Uint32 flags;               /**< Read-only */
    SDL_PixelFormat *format;    /**< Read-only */
    int w, h;                   /**< Read-only */
    int pitch;                  /**< Read-only */
    void *pixels;    
}
```

To run this, in the `main()` function, I get an instance of GameSystem, and then point g_gameSystem from the header file to that instance. Like so:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Initialise the game system core
    GameSystem gameSystem;

    // Make the global gameSystem pointer point to this instance
    g_gameSystem = &gameSystem;
```

My question is: how can I get the values of the `format` property to use the screenFormat function like this: `g_gameSystem->screenFormat()`

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: with `g_gameSystem->screenFormat()->propname` (if I understood your Q correctly), but I strongly suggest you drop the whole static shenanigan and use dependency injection to pass the instance from `main` to your other functions.

Comment: Also, unrelated, but you should consider making read-only things private, and providing accessors that return `const` values.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question, since I'm assuming that `m_screen` is properly initialized in your constructor:

```
g_gameSystem->screenFormat()->someVariable
```

Also, some unsolicited advice, [do not use Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Disadvantages).

Comment: I don't see why the code wouldn't work correctly, given that the lifetime of his variable extends to the end of `main`, so essentially until the end of the program. Your advice just makes it leak.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz You're right, I removed the mention of the stack reference. I included it more as a warning to avoid doing this in general as it can be dangerous, and the OP says he's new to C++ and it's a common mistake.

Comment: I tried this but got the error "argument of type "Uint32" is incompatible with parameter of type "const SDL_PixelFormat *". I know this is another question but I don't know how to fix this either.

Comment: Would I need to cast the result as const SDL_PixelFormat and then return it?

Comment: @JoshBrown oh wait I've just realized my comment (and this answer) are completely wrong. `screenFormat` returns a format already. Post the actual code you tried and the error you got.

Comment: My code remains the same as above. I think the bug's actually in where I'm passing the result of `GameSystem::screenFormat()` to this `SDL_ConvertSurface` function, these are its parameters: SDL_Surface * src, const SDL_PixelFormat * fmt, Uint32 flags

The error is currently `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "class GameSystem * g_gameSystem" (?g_gameSystem@@3PAVGameSystem@@A) SDL`

But it gives live number 1 as the error error is in the .obj file